# How to create a program that counts number of works and characters in a line in C++ WITHOUT using #include <string>

Tags: c++

I am having a problem

Does anyone knows how to create a program using just loops and `iostream` that calculates number of characters (including whitespace/tab/spacebar) in a sentence.

The catch is that `#include string`, `#include fstring` is not allowed to be used in the program.

Only libraries allowed is `iomanip`, `iostream`, `cmath`. Also arrays is not allowed to be used.

I hope you could help me with this problem. Thank you in advance. Good day

Comment: use `while(c = ifstream.get()){}`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a homework assignment, and shows no original effort.

Comment: You start counting before you get the first char from the input... For an empty string, you will get `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For counting characters, you can read the characters in one-by-one (see [`istream::get()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/)), maintaining a count until you hit an end-of-sentence marker. That means something like (pseudo-code, since only classwork tends to have these bizarre limitations and you'll learn very little if we do the work for you):

```
# Initial count.

set charCount to 0

# Process every character until end of sentence.

set ch to getNextChar()
while ch is not end-of-sentence:
    # Each character increments the count.

    add 1 to charCount

    # Go get next character.

    set ch to getNextChar()
```

At the end of that loop, you have the character count (including spaces).

Getting a word count is slightly trickier but you can do it by simply maintaining the state of the last character (state being either SPACE or NONSPACE).

A word ends when you transition from NONSPACE to SPACE. That means you can use conditional statements within that loop to increment a `wordCount` variable on one of those transitions.

Just watch out for the edge case when you hit the end-of-sentence marker and the previous state was NONSPACE, that's *also* a word ending.

A good start for that code for counting both characters and words would be (though it's up to *you* to implement and debug):

```
# Initial counts and state.

set charCount to 0
set wordCount to 0
set prevState to SPACE

# Process every character until end of sentence.

set ch to getNextChar()
while ch != end-of-sentence:
    # Characters are easy.

    add 1 to charCount

    # Get state of current character.

    if ch is a space:
        set currState to SPACE
    else:
        set currState to NONSPACE

    # Word end detected when transition NONSPACE to SPACE.

    if prevState is NONSPACE and currState is SPACE:
        add 1 to wordCount

    # Update previous state and get next character.

    set prevState to currState
    set ch to getNextChar()

# Edge case, word at end of sentence.

if prevState is NONSPACE:
    add 1 to wordCount
```

Answer (score 0):

We won't give you code for something that looks like a homework assignment, but you'll probably want to have one loop calling `cin.get()`, and then check each character as it comes in.